# Laravel and Carbon - DiffInDays If Statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I think I have a relatively simple question, I just think I'm misunderstanding an aspect of it.

I have an index page where in one of the table cells I have an if statement:

```
 @if (Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date)->diffInDays(false) > 0 && Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date)->diffInDays(false) < 10)
```

Where the falses are is where I would like to declare that if the day is in the future, say like tomorrow compared to today, I will have a -1 returned, whereas if I refer to yesterday, I will have a 1 returned.

The problem is I am trying to use the docs but they are lining up for me no matter what sort of way I try them: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

However I should mention that on the same layout I can do this:

```
{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date)->diffInDays()}}
```

and return the number of days in the past or future (even though both are positive) so I know the above works (in a way, but I still need the positive or negative mentioned).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to provide a Carbon date as the first parameter for `diffInDays()`. So, the logic will be:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date)->diffInDays(now(), false)
```

Or:

```
now()->diffInDays(Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date), false)
```

Depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

`false` as the second parameter makes the method return signed value (positive or negative).

Comment: you're saving my day . . .

Comment: you are champion Alexey

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date)->diffInDays(null, false)
```

in place of

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date)->diffInDays(false)
```

This is becuase method signature looks like this:

```
public function diffInDays(Carbon $dt = null, $abs = true)
{
    $dt = $dt ?: static::now($this->getTimezone());

    return (int) $this->diff($dt, $abs)->format('%r%a');
}
```

In addition looking at your logic I think it's too complicated. I think it would be enough to use:

```
@if (Carbon\Carbon::parse($shipment->due_date)->diffInDays(null, false) < 10)
```

the first condition is not necessary I believe

Also in case you are using Laravel 5.5 you should rather use:

```
Illuminate\Support\Carbon
```

instead of

```
Carbon\Carbon
```

in case you wanted to add some custom methods to this class.