# Laravel Carbon using diffInDays and now()

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I managed to solve my previous problem which is counting the days left from `due_date` until today's date. The problem that I'm currently facing is even though the `due_date` is already passed, but is still counting the different days. Supposedly I want to make the output something like `Overdue`. To be more clearer, I show the example below:

[image]

For the third one, supposedly the days left should be negative or showing `Overdue` since today's date is 15/10/2020. Other 2 is correct I think? So how can I solve this?

**complaints table**

```
id
defect_id
created_at (date)
due_date (date)
updated_at (timestamp)
```

**ComplaintController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (count($request->defect_id) > 0) {
            foreach($request->defect_id as $item=>$v) {
                $data = array(    
                    'defect_id' => $request->defect_id[$item],               
                    'created_at' => Carbon::today()->toDateString(),
                    'due_date' => Carbon::today()->addDays(30),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                );

                Complaint::insert($data);
            }
        }
        return redirect('/report-form')->with('success','Your report is submitted!');
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Pending Report</strong></h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="report-table">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Types of Defect</th>
              <th>Report Date</th>
              <th>Due Date</th>
              <th>Days Left</th>
              <th></th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($complaint as $c)
           <tr>
              <td>{{$c->defect->name}}</td>
              <td>{{$c->created_at->format("d/m/yy")}}</td>
              <td>{{date('d/m/yy', strtotime($c->due_date))}}</td>
              @if( \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) <= 10 && \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) > 0 )
                  <td class="text-danger">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) }} days</td>
              @elseif( \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) > 10)
                  <td class="text-success">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) }} days</td>
              @else
                  <td class="text-danger">Overdue</td>
              @endif
              <td><a href="/report/{{$c->id}}/view" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>
           </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
```

There is nothing declared in the model for the `date`. I'm hoping for someone to teach and show me one by one what I need to do.

**--Update--**

```
@if( \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) <= 10 && \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) > 0 )
    <td class="text-danger">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) }} days</td>
 @elseif( \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) > 10)
    <td class="text-success">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) }} days</td>
@elseif( \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now()) < 0)
    <td class="text-success">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now(), false) }} days</td>
@endif
```

Comment: don't you think you need to `parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays($c->created_at)` diff from `created_at` rather then `now()` .?

Comment: Add false as second parameter, echo $dt->diffInDays($dt->copy()->subMonth(), false);                  // -31 It will return days in negative number.

Comment: `created_at` is the date that the complaint has been made by the resident. The contractor only have 30 days (already store in due date) to fix the defects. I use `now()` because I want to alert the contractor to see how many days left between today date and the `due_date`. Do you get it what I means? @KamleshPaul

Comment: So in my case I need to do `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date)->diffInDays(now(), false) }}`? @AnuratChapanond

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel and Carbon - DiffInDays If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946778/laravel-and-carbon-diffindays-if-statement)

Comment: ohh then you can pass third parameter `true` or `false` in `diffInDays` it will return negative or positive value

Comment: @ihz Yes, I think that's it.

Comment: @KamleshPaul I still don't get it. Can you check if I'm done it correctly or not in my **--Update--** code above? If you don't mind please show me the correct code from the beginning.

Comment: @ihz I did not see any wrong on your code , you compare `$c->due_date` with `now()`, and it gives the correct output

Comment: but if the `due_date` has passed from today's date, it should be negative. It is not just I want to differentiate how many days between `due_date` and `now()` @sta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and make it cleaner by separating out the logic a little.

Make use of the `isPast()` and `diffForHumans()` carbon methods.

Then use ternary and if statements later based on the logic laid out beforehand.

Something like:

```
@foreach($complaint as $c)
    @php
        $dueDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($c->due_date);
        $dueSoon = $dueDate->diffInDays(now()) <= 10 && $dueDate->diffInDays(now()) > 0;
        $isPast = $dueDate->isPast();
    @endphp
    <tr>
        <td>{{$c->defect->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$c->created_at->format("d/m/yy")}}</td>
        <td>{{date('d/m/yy', strtotime($c->due_date))}}</td>
        <td class="{{ ($isPast || $dueSoon) ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success' }}">
            @if($isPast)
                Overdue
            @else
                {{ $dueDate->diffForHumans() }}
            @endif
        </td>
        <td><a href="/report/{{$c->id}}/view" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a **[Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)** date as the first parameter for `diffInDays()`. So, the logic will be:

```
$c->due_date->diffInDays(now(), false); // -29
```

Or,

```
now()->diffInDays($c->due_date, false); // 29
```

`false` as the second parameter makes the method return signed value (**positive** or **negative**). Without this parameter `diffInDays()` will return **positive** value

**Example** :

```
$i = $data->created_at; // 2020-10-21 11:31:37
$q = $i->diffInDays(now(), false); // now() = 2020-10-15 16:40:49
dd($q); // -6
```

Comment: Ya, if you look on my post, I have edited my code under **--Update--** I already put `false`, but still nothing changed. Or did I misplaced it?

Comment: @ihz I've tested both code, and boths are working as above example

Comment: above example is I want to show the wrong output that I got. for the last row, it does not count correctly as what I want. It should be `-6 days`

Comment: @ihz, I checked on my side, and get the `-6` as output, I edited my answer and attached that code above that I have just tested